# CAST/CONVERT problem Arithmetic overflow error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

`SELECT` works, but `UPDATE` does not.

Every version of `CAST` and `CONVERT`

I'm getting this error:

> Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric

When I try to do this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE rentinc ".
       "SET curr_loss_mo = ROUND(CONVERT(numeric(3,0), DATEDIFF(DAY, missincdate, GETDATE()) / 30), 0) ".
       "WHERE months2 > 12";
```

I'm pretty sure there's overkill in the code above, but I was trying EVERYTHING.

I can go to SSMS and run this SELECT:

```
SELECT curr_loss_mo, ROUND(CONVERT(numeric(3, 0), DATEDIFF(DAY, missincdate, GETDATE()) / 30), 0) AS DateNumCalc
FROM rentinc
WHERE months2 > 12
```

And it works fine.  And the two columns look exactly the same!  The `curr_loss_mo` field is a `numeric(3,0)` and there are no values in the table that will try to update with more than three characters.

So why am I getting this error?

> "Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric"

Comment: I don't quite get what the two queries have to do with each other.  They have different filtering conditions, so they are not working on the same set of rows.

Comment: You have different `WHERE` conditions on the two queries. Try using the same condition in `MMS`, it's probably a case where `curr_loss_mo IS NULL` which is causing your problem

Comment: Is this a SQL Server query? If so, please tag as such

Comment: The expression should fit within a `numeric(3,0)` for all values of `missincdate` between July 12, 1937 and Oct 19, 2101 (as of roughly today.) Since the error indicates that a conversion from `int` is the one causing a problem, I do think it has to be caused by the `round()` function. What is the column type for your date value? As already pointed out the filters are not the same. Do you have any blanks or zeroes being treated as Jan 1, 1900?

Comment: From the description of [tag:sql]: * Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead.*

Comment: In reply to some of the replies... Shame on me for not matching the two WHEREs exactly, but I've changed that and tested and the situation is the same.  Again, I don't get an error on the SELECT and the column returned is at most 3 digits.  To the person mentioning the ROUND(), I added that when it didn't work without it, thinking perhaps it was needed.  But still... I get the error. Anyone?  To those criticizing my tagging (but not giving an answer), I'm learning how to do this and have amended the tags.

Comment: Try inserting into a brand new table (for testing purposes.) This should help eliminate the possibility of computed columns or triggers from coming into play.

Comment: `rentinc` and `temp_rentinc` are different tables. Do they have the same schema?

Comment: Another mea culpa on my part.  The two tables are identical and I've changed the above code to reflect that.  I will try the suggestion above about a new table, but I doubt this will do anything.  There are no triggers on the table whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, this mystery got even deeper, but I found a workaround, so I took care of it.

I had made a temporary copy of the rentinc table called temp_rentinc.  It is an EXACT COPY, as in "SELECT  * INTO temp_rentinc FROM  rentinc."

For reasons that totally baffle me, the UPDATE code I posted above worked with temp_rentinc, but not with rentinc! Baffled, I wrote a program to compare the structures via "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'each table name.'

The program verified that they were EXACTLY THE SAME.  Sigh.  Sometimes, the gremlins just get you.  To make a long story short, I killed the original table, and reversed the SELECT INTO to re-create the table and the code now works fine.

This goes in the "WTF?" file.  Thanks everyone for your input.
-- John